# Airflow: how to access running task from task instance?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

This is my situation:

I am trying to access the instance of my custom operator running in another DAG. I am able to get the correct DagRun and TaskInstance objects by doing the following.

```
dag_bag = DagBag(settings.DAGS_FOLDER)
target_dag = dag_bag.get_dag('target_dag_id')
dr = target_dag.get_dagrun(target_dag.latest_execution_date)
ti = dr.get_task_instance('target_task_id')
```

I have printed the TaskInstance object aquired by the above lines and it is correct (it is running/has the correct task_id etc.), however when I am unable to access the task object, which would allow me to interface with the running operator. I should be able to do the following:

`running_custom_operator = ti.task #AttributeError: TaskInstance has not attribute task`

Any help would be much appreciated, either following my approach or if someone knows how to access the task object of a running task instance.

Thank you

Comment: `task_instance` is basically the running task. To make sure to retrieve `task_instance.end_date` this will show you the end of the running task.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply grab the task object from the `DAG` object: `target_dag.task_dict["target_task_id"]`

Comment: Yes but this does not give the instance of the running task. target_dag.task_dict["target_task_id"] gives a new instance of the operator, I need the specific instance of the task connected to the DagRun whose attributes will have different values than a newly instantiated operator of the same variety. Thank you for your suggestion though

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly, you've shown you already have access to the TaskInstance object. Do you want the rendered attributes according to the run context?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to interface/interact with an instance of an operator running in another dag.

Comment: @EliasPosen any updates on this? Stuck on the same thing, would want to access rendered template of an operator of the previous dag run

Comment: @Sabyasachi this is doable if you'd like to open a question.

Comment: @EliasPosen What are you trying to **accomplish** if you had that object what would you do?

Comment: Not sure what OP was trying to accomplish, but I have a similar need with the following use: When using the KubernetesPodOperator, the pod id is created in part with a uuid. I want to capture that pod id in a later task in the same dag, which seems like it's require accessing a task instance's post-execution operator attributes.

Comment: @ZaxR Perhaps a post-callback that inserts the value as an XCom?